# random repeating shapes

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

So I was playing with desmos and I was entering a random sum of sines and cosines and I noticed I had a weird shape forming.

So compactly written, what I was basically noticing was $\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{\sin((2n+1)x}{2n+1}$ was a rectangle thingy.

And then when I put a $(-1)^n$ and squared the denominator, it turned into a triangle!

So lets say I have a random function. And lets say I want to splice the portion from $(0,2π)$ and turn that into a periodic function. Is there some way to do that??? And it would have to be only sine and cosine because they are repeating.

Comment: Are you asking about [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series)?

Comment: I know what Taylor series is @hardmath

Comment: omg! this is exactly what i'm looking for @hardmath

Comment: Taylor series do not typically give us a periodic function, but Fourier series (see my link) are composed of sine and cosine harmonics (frequency multiples) and are therefore guaranteed to be periodic

Comment: Fourier series turn up in many places.  Students often are introduced to them in connection with separation of variables solutions to PDEs like the heat equation in an undergraduate course.  History of the theory of Fourier series may be related in some relevant posts at [HSM.SE](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/search?q=fourier+series+is%3Aquestion).

Comment: Yes it is very classical. Have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave) you will see there your series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the Fourier Series on wikipedia.